# IFFHS football club rankings formula?

Tags: football, ranking

https://www.iffhs.com/posts/2486

There is a football club rankings for almost all the clubs.

Is there a formula for calculating the points for these rankings?

I searched for it but could never find it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for this club ranking.

A club is given a point each time they win a regular season game in their domestic league or continental club competition such as UEFA Champions League or  Copa Libertadores.

A team receives 4 points for a win and 2 points for a draw in the top domestic league, and fewer points for the second, third, and fourth-tier league.

A win in the UEFA Champions League and Copa Libertadores won 14 points and a win in the AFC or CAF Champions League won 12 points. A draw is always half the points of win. A second-tier continental competition gives less points that the top-tier competition.

The full table can be found in the archived version of the original document.

[Point table](http://web.archive.org/web/20131002064048/http://www.iffhs.de/?bc83ccac3be8e00390b02fc5fdcdc3bfcdc0aec70aeed10a)

The original document on the IFFHS website was removed but the archived version exists.